# Spark map closure not getting free variables inside

Tags: scala, apache-spark, closures, distributed-computing

I'm trying to do a transform with map -> combineByKey -> map on an RDD.

I have this driver method which initialized a sparkSession:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName(getClass.getName).getOrCreate()

    val originalRdd = ...

    new A.transform(spark, originalRdd) 
  }
```

Then in transform function, I initialized another variable.

first map: turn it into key value pairs, second map: convert the list values and call f and g

```
class A {
 
  def transform(spark: sparkSession, originalRdd: RDD) = {

    val b = new B()

    val rdd = originalRdd
        .map {
          s => ((s.a, s.b, s.c), (s.d, s.e)) 
        }.combineByKey(
          // define combiner to combine the tuples to a list
        ).map {
          case (k, v) => Seq((k, b.f(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(v)), b.g(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(v))) // "b" and "sparkContext" will always be null here and throw NullPointerException on this line
        }

        rdd
   }

}
```

I need to use **b** to call f and g, both take the RDD with values and calculate a number based on the values, neither updates the input RDD itself in anyway. and spark to convert **v** to an RDD and pass it into f and g in this closure.

I tried wrapping those two in broadcast to keep a read-only cache of these two variables on the cluster executors inside transform(), and using these in the closure instead:

```
      val broadcastBVar = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(b)
      val broadcastSpark = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(spark)

      broadcastBVar.value //usage
```

this didn't work either, i still got the NPE. is there any way to workaround this issue?

Comment: Can you clarify where the NPE occurs? For sure you don't need to broadcast the `SparkSession` nor `SparkContext`. For your `B` it depends on what it actually is and what it does.

Comment: @GaëlJ i updated the description for `B`. i also commented on the line which throws NPE